# Call to a member function fetchObject() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

breaks at my while loop. have been reading the php manual but can't figure out what im doing wrong here...

$pdo is call to my db connection

```
function getSelectedPhoto($the_selected_id) {
global $pdo;

$id = $the_selected_id;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT handle, src FROM images WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
$vars = array(':id' => $id);
$result = $stmt->execute($vars);

if($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
        echo '<img src="../' . $row->src . '" alt="image" /><br />';
        echo '<p id="handle">' . $row->handle . '</p>';
    } 
} else die("There was some problem");
```

}

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump($result)?

Comment: Please do not use global, instead look for dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual "[PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)" the `execute()`-method returns `true` or `false` and not the result:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Of course this will lead to *"Call to a member function fetchObject() on a non-object"* when calling `$result->fetchObject()`.

Your code should be like this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute($vars);

if ($result) {
    while( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() ) {}
}
```

Comment: overlooked this due to staring at code all day long! much obliged.